# How to convert image data so it can be JSON serializable and vice versa

Tags: python, django

How can i make image data JSON serializable and then convert it back so it can be saved as a image.

I get the error:     `<InMemoryUploadedFile: image.jpg (image/jpeg)> is not JSON serializable`

```
def imageFileView(request):

    form = ImageFileForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid:
            image = request.FILES.get('image')
            image_file = request.session['image_file'] = image 
            return redirect('picxs:create')

def imageView(request):

    img_file = request.session.get('image_file')
    img_temp = NamedTemporaryFile('w')
    img_temp.write(img_file)
    img_temp.flush()

    form = SaveImageForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if request.post == 'POST':
       if form.is_valid:
           instance = form.save(commit=False)
           instance.image.save(img_filename, File(img_temp), save = True)
```

Comment: I have zero experience in Python, but can you Base64 encode the binary file and then treat it as a string?  You'll get about a 30% increase in size doing this, but the approach works in other languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
img_file = request.session.get('image_file')
json.dumps(str(my_imagefield))
```

this should work for storing the image in the memory

or using `base64`

```
import base64
img_file = request.session.get('image_file')
with open(img_file , "wb") as fh:
    fh.write(base64.decodebytes(img_data))
```

Comment: Is there an advantage of using a base64?

Comment: yes, its the best technique available for image objects to be converted to json format to hold up in the memory, it generates a big string and is faster in the memoryh

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options and which you use will vary on your use case.

You can get the raw bytes of the image and return the serialized byte array.

You can get the raw bytes of the image and convert the bytes to hex and return the hex string.

Or you can get the raw bytes of the image and convert the bytes to a base64 string and return the base64 string.

As a side note `InMemoryUploadedFile` is a wrapper to to get the actual file you need to use `.file`