# Python - convert image to JSON

Tags: python, json

I need to convert an image (can be any type jpg, png etc.) to JSON serializable.

I looked into the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135892/how-to-convert-image-data-so-it-can-be-json-serializable-and-vice-versa) but the accepted solution has a typo and I am not sure how to resolve it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This might get you started:

```
import json
import base64

data = {}
with open('some.gif', mode='rb') as file:
    img = file.read()
data['img'] = base64.encodebytes(img).decode('utf-8')

print(json.dumps(data))
```

Answer (score 6):

**Python 2**

As the `base64.encodebytes()` has been deprecated in base64, the code snippet above can be modified as follows:

```
import json
import base64

data = {}
with open('some.gif', mode='rb') as file:
    img = file.read()

data['img'] = base64.b64encode(img)
print(json.dumps(data))
```

Then, use `base64.b64decode(data['img'])` to convert back.

Comment: Did you mean to write "Python 3" in the heading?

Answer (score 0):

You should first convert the image into a string. Suppose you loaded the image with `Image.open('/path/to/image')`, then you could do:

```
import io
import base64
from PIL import Image

def image2string(image: Image.Image, _format: str = 'PNG') -> str:
    r""" Convert Pillow image to string. """
    if _format == 'JPEG':
        image = image.convert('RGB')
    img_bytes_arr = io.BytesIO()
    image.save(img_bytes_arr, format=_format)
    img_bytes_arr.seek(0)
    img_bytes_arr = img_bytes_arr.read()
    img_bytes_arr_encoded = base64.b64encode(img_bytes_arr)
    res = img_bytes_arr_encoded.decode('utf-8')
    return res


def string2image(string: str) -> Image.Image:
    r""" Convert string to Pillow image. """
    img_bytes_arr = string.encode('utf-8')
    img_bytes_arr_encoded = base64.b64decode(img_bytes_arr)
    image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(img_bytes_arr_encoded))
    return image
```

Then, use `image2string` to transform you image into a string that you could put into JSON files. `string2image` allows you to convert the string back into a `Pillow` image.