# Altair tooltip with local PIL image

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-imaging-library, altair

Following the official example from the [docs](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/image_tooltip.html) I can successfully create an altair scatter plot with each point having a tooltip:

```py
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

source = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
    [{'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'image': 'https://altair-viz.github.io/_static/altair-logo-light.png'},
     {'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'image': 'https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/11796929?s=200&v=4'}]
)
alt.Chart(source).mark_circle(size=200).encode(
    x='a',
    y='b',
    tooltip=['image']  # Must be a list for the image to render
)
```

#### The result will look as follows

[image: before code change]

However I want to use a local image which I loaded via PIL. If i just replace the URL-string with the PIL object in the tooltip I get the error: `TypeError: Object of type 'Image' is not JSON serializable`.

I then tried to convert to image to JSON following this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54661844/5105118)

My code now looks as follows:

```py
import json
from io import BytesIO
import base64
def image_formatter2(im):
    with BytesIO() as buffer:
        im.save(buffer, 'png')
        data = base64.encodebytes(buffer.getvalue()).decode('utf-8')
    
    return json.dumps(data)
    


temp = some_local_PIL_image.thumbnail((90,90))

source = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
    [{'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'image': image_formatter2(temp)},
     {'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'image': 'https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/11796929?s=200&v=4'}]
)
alt.Chart(source).mark_circle(size=200).encode(
    x='a',
    y='b',
    tooltip=['image']  # Must be a list for the image to render
)
```

My tooltip is now empty! How can I display the local image in the tooltip?

[image: after code change]

---

Version info

```
IPython          : 7.16.1
jupyter_client   : 7.0.6
jupyter_core     : 4.8.1
altair           : 4.1.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I kind of figured it out. One has to add a prefix `data:image/png;base64,` to the data. The code is now as follows:

```py
import PIL.Image
from io import BytesIO
import base64
import json

def image_formatter2(im):
    with BytesIO() as buffer:
        im.save(buffer, 'png')
        data = base64.encodebytes(buffer.getvalue()).decode('utf-8')
    
    return f"data:image/png;base64,{data}" # <--------- this prefix is crucial
    


temp = some_local_PIL_image.thumbnail((90,90))

source = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
    [{'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'image': image_formatter2(temp)},
     {'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'image': 'https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/11796929?s=200&v=4'}]
)
alt.Chart(source).mark_circle(size=200).encode(
    x='a',
    y='b',
    tooltip=['image']  # Must be a list for the image to render
)
```

### Result

[image: final result]

---

Since I didn't know the term/syntax and this may help others as well:
The term one has to look for is `Data URLs`. Here is a nice intro: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs

Comment: I tried to find a solution to this problem, but it was already answered by myself. I did not put the string in the return value of the function, but added it to the data frame of the source. +1 for your answer.

Comment: You can find some discussion on this in the last two comments here https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/2318

Comment: The image column of the dataframe to plot must have name "image". Other names will results in the tooltip being displayed as a string. altair version 5.2.0