FastAPI Application python error JSON not serializable
I'm coding an API with FastAPI for this project TripoSR
My code at this moment is following (I only need this 2 functions):
from fastapi import FastAPI
from gradio_app import preprocess, generate

# initialise FastAPI instance
app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/tripo-api")
def generator(input_image, do_remove_background: bool, foreground_ratio: float, mc_resolution, formats=["obj", "glb"]):
    """
    Generator function, which calls preprocessing and generating function

    Parameters:
      - input_image, data type: PIL.Image.Image
      - do_remove_background, data type: boolean
      - foreground_ratio, data type: float
    """

    # call preprocessing function with given parameters
    output_prepr = preprocess(input_image=input_image, do_remove_background=do_remove_background, foreground_ratio=foreground_ratio)

    # call generate function, based on prepocessing
    rv = generate(output_prepr, mc_resolution=mc_resolution, formats=formats)
    
    return {rv}

The error I'm getting when I try to call this api is following:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\TripoSR\api_test.py", line 30, in <module>
    response = requests.post(url, json=payload)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python\3.11\Lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 115, in post
    return request("post", url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python\3.11\Lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python\3.11\Lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 575, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python\3.11\Lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 486, in prepare_request
    p.prepare(
  File "C:\Python\3.11\Lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 371, in prepare
    self.prepare_body(data, files, json)
  File "C:\Python\3.11\Lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 511, in prepare_body
    body = complexjson.dumps(json, allow_nan=False)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python\3.11\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python\3.11\Lib\json\encoder.py", line 200, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python\3.11\Lib\json\encoder.py", line 258, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python\3.11\Lib\json\encoder.py", line 180, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable

I'm calling the api with following python code:
import requests
from PIL import Image
import io

# API endpoint
url = "http://localhost:8000/tripo-api"

# Example input parameters
input_image = Image.open("examples\captured.jpeg")
do_remove_background = True
foreground_ratio = 0.8
mc_resolution = 512
formats = ["obj", "glb"]

# Convert the input image to bytes
img_bytes = io.BytesIO()
input_image.save(img_bytes, format='JPEG')
img_bytes = img_bytes.getvalue()

# Prepare the request payload
payload = {
    "input_image": img_bytes,
    "do_remove_background": do_remove_background,
    "foreground_ratio": foreground_ratio,
    "mc_resolution": mc_resolution,
    "formats": formats
}

# Send the POST request to the API
response = requests.post(url, json=payload)

# Check the response
if response.status_code == 200:
    print("API request successful!")
    print(response.json())
else:
    print("API request failed with status code:", response.status_code)
    print("Error message:", response.text)

The idea behind this is, to build an own frontend around this project. For this I need an API, so that's the reason why I write this. If anyone know help, would be very helpful!

issue is most likely with first line of the payload init..  img_bytes is bytes string which as-is cannot be serialized to json. You probably need to encode that bytes string to base64 string first and then on the flask side, decode it back to bytes.  See; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54660800/python-convert-image-to-json

return {rv} - this also creates a set - which isn't representable in JSON.

How to change that with the set, that's representable in JSON? @MatsLindh

That depends on what you want to return; if it's just a single object, just return a dictionary with the fields you want to include from rv. And convert any binary data to base64 as rasjani said.

I want to return that, what the generate function returns to me:
def generate(image, mc_resolution, formats=["obj", "glb"]):
    scene_codes = model(image, device=device)
    mesh = model.extract_mesh(scene_codes, resolution=mc_resolution)[0]
    mesh = to_gradio_3d_orientation(mesh)
    rv = []
    for format in formats:
        mesh_path = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=f".{format}", delete=False)
        mesh.export(mesh_path.name)
        rv.append(mesh_path.name)
    return rv


@MatsLindh that should be a list, how to return that?

Then you return rv directly, and define a response_class=List[<model that describes each object in the list>)

You could alternatively return a custom Response directly ,as shown in this answer, as well as this answer and this answer

If you're considering sending any file within a JSON payload, it's common practice to encode it in base64 format. However, this method often leads to long and messy strings, which isn't ideal.
An alternative approach could be:

Utilizing a dedicated endpoint in FastAPI, like UploadFile(..).
Generating an image and uploading it to a cloud service such as an AWS bucket, then returning its link within your JSON response.


The input_image in the request payload seems to be of bytes data-type. Typically, while sending an image file in a request payload, you want to encode it to Base-64 format.
Encoding the input_image and sending it as a string should resolve your error.
You can then decode the Base64 encoded image file in your generator endpoint.
